# How to use sass string replace in data:image string?

Tags: sass

I'm using string replace mentioned on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/str-replace-function/)

But I'm trying to do string replace within background image `data:image/svg+xml` string

I'm am trying to replace one of my color vars hex `#` with url encoded `%23`.

I don't think the stack snippet works with SASS but getting same results in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/e7rb4xwv/).

You can see better in sassmeister the css output https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7cf11bf6f3ee4951cf67e0e6074d1d67

```css
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);
  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }
  @return $string;
}

$wm-black : #202020;

.modal-close {
  &:before {
    background: {
      image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 320 512"><style>.a{fill:%23' + str-replace( $wm-black, '#', '%23' ) + '}</style><path class="a" d="M193.94 256L296.5 153.44l21.15-21.15c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31l-22.63-22.63c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L160 222.06 36.29 98.34c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L2.34 120.97c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31L126.06 256 2.34 379.71c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l22.63 22.63c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0L160 289.94 262.56 392.5l21.15 21.15c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l22.63-22.63c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31L193.94 256z"/></svg>');
      repeat: no-repeat;
      position: calc(100% - 25px) 25px;
      size: 36px 36px;
      color: rgba(#000,.95);
    }
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="modal-close"></button>
```

In PHP storm, the string parameter var is not working as it should so not valid.

[image]

My code currently fails to compile, so something is up but not sure why str-replace function wont  return here.

Error code.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: $string: #202020 is not a string.
  ╷
4 │   $index: str-index($string, $search);
  │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/scss/_functions.scss 4:11  str-replace()
```

Thanks

---

**Update:** I've also tried this method, syntax looks better but still not compiling.

[image]

See it compiling in Sassmeister... https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c9569c0373b52f0a9b3f8ae07860f8af

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interpolate and convert the color value into a string:

```scss
#{str-replace('' + $wm-black, '#', '%23')}
```

Example usage...

```scss
$wm-black : #202020;

.bg-svg {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><style>.a{fill:#{str-replace('' + $wm-black, '#', '%23')};}</style></svg>');
}
```

Comment: I did find a solution in the end and forgot to post my solution as an update. Same principle, convert variable value to string. I will post solution as an answer too. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@MiguelPynto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553103/miguel-pynto) for your answer, this is my solution which I am currently using, but same principle.

```scss
#{str-replace(#{$wm-black}, '#', '%23')}
```

Example usage below...

```scss
$wm-black : #202020;

.bg-svg {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><style>.a{fill:#{str-replace(#{$wm-black},'#','%23')};}</style></svg>');
}
```